# Undefined reference to Classname::Classname() and other errors

Tags: c++

This is a noob question, sorry, I'm coming from Java and have no idea why my OO stuff isn't working. I have this main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Foo.h" //changed name
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
  int choice;
  cin >> choice;

  Foo net;
  switch(choice)
    {
    case 1: net.buildNetwork(); break;
    }
}
```

This `Foo.h` file:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H
#include <iostream>
struct City{
    std::string cityName;
    std::string message;
    City *next;

    City(){}; // default constructor

    City(std::string initName, City *initNext, std::string initMessage)
    {
        cityName = initName;
        next = initNext;
        message = initMessage;
    }

};

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo();
        ~Foo();
        void addCity(std::string, std::string);
        void buildNetwork();
        void transmitMsg(char *); //this is like a string
        void printNetwork();
    protected:
    private:
        City *head;
        City *tail;
};

#endif // FOO_H
```

And this `Foo.cpp` file, all in the same directory:

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Foo::Foo()
{
    head = tail = NULL;
}

Foo::~Foo(){}

void Foo::buildNetwork()
{
  cout << "works" << endl;
}
void Foo::transmitMsg(){}
void Foo::printNetwork(){}
void Foo::addCity(){}
```

When I compile, I get

```
/tmp/ccNx3fY5.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `Foo::Foo()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `Foo::buildNetwork()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `Foo::~Foo()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `Foo::~Foo()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What's wrong? Also, another question: in `Foo.cpp`, why do I need `Foo::Foo()` etc? I used `namespace std`, so why can't I just say `Foo()`?

Comment: What is your compile command?

Comment: `g++ main.cpp -o main`

Comment: You forgot to include foo.cpp when compiling? If you just compile main.cpp by itself, then the compiler is right - your program *doesn't* contain those functions, because foo.cpp isn't part of your program unless you say it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the way you compile, you are only providing only one source file (main.cpp) whereas the correct way is to specify all the source files. In your case, it would be:

```
g++ main.cpp foo.cpp -o executable
```

The "undefined reference" error is a error thrown at the linking stage when the linker can't resolve the names correctly because, you didn't link the source files properly like above.

Additionally, make sure that when you declare a function prototype, the implementation of the function should also have the same signature. In your example, you provided the function prototypes as:

```
void transmitMsg(char *);
void addCity(std::string, std::string);
```

But your implementation of those functions don't have the correct signature. They should have been:

```
void Foo::transmitMsg(char *){}

void Foo::addCity(std::string, std::string){}
```

> why do I need Foo::Foo() etc?

Because Foo() is a function of the class Foo.

> I used namespace std, so why can't I just say Foo()?

When you make a call to using namespace ; all symbols in that namespace will become visible without adding the namespace prefix. A symbol may be for instance a function, class or a variable.

Foo is not a namespace like "std". It is a user-defined class.

Answer (score 2):

> Also, another question: in Foo.cpp, why do I need Foo::Foo() etc? I
>   used namespace std, so why can't I just say Foo()?

You need to write `Foo::Foo()` in `foo.cpp` because you are defining the constructor outside the body of the `Foo` class which is present in `foo.h`.
`std` is the standard namespace and using that in no way absolves you from referring to the `Foo` class you have created since its not a part of the standard namespace

Comment: so can I say `using namespace Foo;`?

Comment: @RenéG No, because `Foo` isn't a namespace name, it's a class name.

Comment: nope since you haven't created a namespace named as `Foo`. You have created a class named `Foo`, that doesn't make it a namespace.
Namespaces are analogous to packages in Java

Answer (score 1):

You have not included `foo.cpp` in your compile command, So this is why you cant link the functions. You need to use the command line argument:

```
g++ main.cpp foo.cpp -o main
```

This allows the compiler to find the functions in `foo.cpp`.